# Facebook FB.ui stops working after the first time

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908904/feed-dialog-fbui-facebook-ui-is-not-working), only I couldn't get a solution from that discussion.
I'm building a page with FB connect, and I need to post something to the user's feed. If I click the button I created for it, the feed popup displays correctly, and I can post to facebook. However, if I navigate to another page or if I refresh the page and then try again, then the popup won't show. There're no errors in the console.
If I log out of facebook and then try to publish again, the popup will show one more time, and then stop working.

**EDIT**
I think it's fixed - by adding the property:
    display: "popup"
I was able to make it work every time.